# How to find a word in Javascript array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, find, collect

My question is, how can I find all array indexes by a word ?

```
[
{name: "Jeff Crawford", tel: "57285"},
{name: "Jeff Maier", tel: "52141"},
{name: "Tim Maier", tel: "73246"}
]
```

If I search for "Jeff", I want to get:

```
[
{name: "Jeff Crawford", tel: "57285"},
{name: "Jeff Maier", tel: "52141"},
]
```

Comment: You have anything that you tried?

Comment: You want only indices or the elements?

Comment: Please visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To make it more versatile, you could take a function which takes an array of objects, the wanted key and the search string, wich is later used as lower case string.

```js
function find(array, key, value) {
    value = value.toLowerCase();
    return array.filter(o => o[key].toLowerCase().includes(value));
}

var array = [{ name: "Jeff Crawford", tel: "57285" }, { name: "Jeff Maier", tel: "52141" }, { name: "Tim Maier", tel: "73246" }]

console.log(find(array, 'name', 'Jeff'));
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `.filter`:

```js
const input=[{name:"Jeff Crawford",tel:"57285"},{name:"Jeff Maier",tel:"52141"},{name:"Tim Maier",tel:"73246"}]
const filtered = input.filter(({ name }) => name.startsWith('Jeff'));
console.log(filtered);
```

If you want to check to see if "Jeff" is *anywhere* rather than only at the beginning, use `.includes` instead:

```js
const input=[{name:"Jeff Crawford",tel:"57285"},{name:"foo-Jeff Maier",tel:"52141"},{name:"Tim Maier",tel:"73246"}]
const filtered = input.filter(({ name }) => name.includes('Jeff'));
console.log(filtered);
```

These are ES6 features. For ES5, use `indexOf` instead:

```js
var input=[{name:"Jeff Crawford",tel:"57285"},{name:"foo-Jeff Maier",tel:"52141"},{name:"Tim Maier",tel:"73246"}]
var filtered = input.filter(function(obj){
  return obj.name.indexOf('Jeff') !== -1;
});
console.log(filtered);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [`Array#map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) on the original array and return the indices. Then [filter out](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) the `undefined` values:

```js
const data = [{name:"Jeff Crawford",tel:"57285"},{name:"Jeff Maier",tel:"52141"},{name:"Tim Maier",tel:"73246"}];

const indices = data.map((item, i) => {
    if (item.name.startsWith('Jeff')) {
      return i;
    }
  })
  .filter(item => item !== undefined);

console.log(indices);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use array `filter` method along with `indexOf`. `filter` will return a new array of matched element. In side the filter callback function check for the name where the `indexOf` the keyword is not `-1`. That is the name should contain the keyword

```js
var originalArray = [{
    name: "Jeff Crawford",
    tel: "57285"
  },
  {
    name: "Jeff Maier",
    tel: "52141"
  },
  {
    name: "Tim Maier",
    tel: "73246"
  }
]

function getMatchedElem(keyWord) {
  return originalArray.filter(function(item) {
    return item.name.indexOf(keyWord) !== -1

  })

}

console.log(getMatchedElem('Jeff'))
```